# How to integrate a voice to string detector in C language

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, detection, voice

I'm new to C programming, I would like to develop a game in unity including some voice detection in order to respond to gamers choices. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Unity primarily uses C#. Are you planning to write a native plugin for Unity? That's far from trivial (and too broad for SO)

Comment: The correct term is called "speech to text".  Google for that.

Answer (score 0):

For so-called Speech To Text, you can use the [KeywordRecognizer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html) or [PhraseRecognizer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognizer.html) as part of UnityEngine.Windows.Speech. Here's an example (fill the words in the Editor Inspector pane to the right):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
// Put this check around any part you want to hide on other systems.
#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
    using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
#endif

public class KeywordScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string[] keywords;

    KeywordRecognizer recognizer;

    void Start()
    {
        recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords);
        recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += OnPhraseRecognized;
        recognizer.Start();
    }

    void OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        print(args.text);
        print(args.confidence);
    }
}
```

Note at least in our project, some users had issues getting this to work depending on specific Operating System details; it also gets trickier when you take into account the various OS language settings. On top of that, words are often simply not understood properly, but this also partially depends on how many command words you filter for; if you only have a small amount of words, and you allow for high error tolerance, you may get good results in that regard.

Also note that this library is Windows-only, so you would need other approaches for e.g. Android or iOS.

Comment: So apparently there is the KeywordRecognizer feature in Unity but as its name indicates it is limited to few "Keywords". I was planning to integrate a speech to text detector for a full dictionnary. Is this possible?

Comment: The OP posted this as a C question; this is not C